# Determine the Automorphism group of the quaternion group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, automorphism-group

Question: Determine ${\rm Aut}(Q_{8})$ for $Q_{8}$ being the quaternion group.
I'm currently self studying some abstract algebra and I am struggling a little bit with this question from Micheal Artin's Algebra book.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Well, 1 has to go to 1, -1 has to go to -1, since it is the only element of order two. Now see where $i, j, k$ can go.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @Shaun Why are you telling me this?

Comment: @Shaun You should know by now that I know at least as much as you do, and so refrain from lecturing.

Answer (score 1):

The elements $1$ and $-1$ are fixed. We can imagine the remaining elements as an octahedron in $3$d space, where multiplying two opposite vertices gives $1$, multiplying a vertex by itself gives $-1$, and multiplying  two adjacent vertices gives their cross product, which is basically finding the vertex such that drawing a loop for the first element to the second element to the product goes counterclockwise around a face, if we are looking from outside the octahedron. Therefore, a symmetry of the quaternion group corresponds to a rotational symmetry of the octahedron. Since the rotational symmetry group of an octahedron is $S_4,$ the automorphism group of $Q_8$ is $S_4.$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.